# Generic type does not fit

Tags: java, generics, graph-theory, dijkstra

I tried to program solutions for a game via Dijkstra algorithm. To learn something new, i tried to use generics, and i failed.

To make everything generic, the nodes have a generic data element that contains the game position, and add distance, predecessor and visited for the Dijkstra algorithm:

```
public final class LSNode<E extends LSElement<?>> {

    private final transient E element;
    private LSNode<E> predecessor;
    private long distance = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    private boolean visited;

    public LSNode(final E element) {
    this.element = element;
    }
... // the usual getters, setters, a hashCode() and equals().
}
```

The elements have to provide knowledge about creating and executing game moves (i.e. moving along an edge), a natural order, hashCode() and equals().

```
public interface LSElement<T> extends Comparable<LSElement<T>> {
    List<T> findLegalMoves();
    LSElement<T> executeMove(T move);
}
```

As each game has it’s own type of move, it is a generic type parameter of LSElement. In my game, it’s a `List<Integer>`, in other games, it can be a game card, a simple `int` or something completely different. So T is any subtype of `Object`, and that needs not to be specified, or so i hope.

This interface specifies implicitely the edges of the graph by knowing how to calculate the data elements of the children of a Node.

The Graph is directed. The weight of all edges is 1. The nodes are stored in a HashMap. Nodes are produced during visiting, and to decide if they are new or if they have to be added to the ordered Collection of unvisited nodes, the node with the same element has to be found and gotten from the nodes collection. A Set doesn't provide a get(), so the nodes are stored in a Map both as key and value. The collection of unvisited nodes is a priority queue, ordered reverse by distance.

```
public class LSGraph<E extends LSElement<?>> {

    private final transient Map<LSNode<E>, LSNode<E>> graph;
    private final transient PriorityQueue<LSNode<E>> queue;

    public LSGraph() {
    graph = new HashMap<>();
    queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingLong(LSNode::getDistance));
    }
```

The Dijkstra is implemented as usual. StartNode, DestNode as parameters. StartNode to graph, startNode to queue. Algorithm terminates if destNode is reached (solution exists) or queue is empty (no solution exists). Head element of queue is taken as actNode. The shortest path to an already visited node is known; if it comes form queue, it can be ignored. The edges (possible game moves) are retrieved for actNode.

```
    LSNode<E> actNode = null;
    LSNode<E> compareNode;
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        actNode = queue.poll();
        if (actNode.equals(destNode)) {
        break;
        }
        compareNode = graph.get(actNode);
        if (compareNode.isVisited()) {
        continue;
        }
        final List<?> moves = actNode.getElement().findLegalMoves();
```

First problem: I cannot iterate over moves, because i don’t know the type of ?. SO told me about a helper function for wildcard capture:

```
        fspHelper(moves, actNode);
    }
  }

  private <M> void fspHelper(final List<M> moves, final LSNode<E> actNode) {
    for (final M move : moves) {
        final LSNode<E> newNode = new LSNode<>(actNode.getElement().executeMove(move));
    }
  }
}
```

And this is where i run into a problem i don’t know how to solve. I want to produce a new LSNode. I have a legal move. I take the actual node, get his data element, and execute the move on this element, then i produce a new LSNode with the new data element. But it doesn’t work. The Compiler tells me:

```
The method executeMove(capture#3-of ?) in the type LSElement<capture#3-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (M)
```

How can this be? The type parameter of LSElement allows really every type, and M is just a type. What have i to do to solve this?

A possible solution would be to make LSElements NOT generic, to make the return type of findLegalMoves() and the parameter type of executeMove() to `Object` and to cast to the proper type in every implementation of LSElement. But are generics not made to avoid this?

Comment: Is there a reason for using the generic wildcard? Something like `LSNode<T, E extends LSElement<T>>` should be a valid option?

Comment: I used a generic wildcard because i did not know any other possibility. In my opinion, your (untested) proposal should work but would violate encapsulation. No one but the implementor of a specific `LSElement<T>` should need to know about the type of a move. If i would make this type a type parameter of LSNode i would have the feeling of a slight code smell. But these are only theoretical thougts.

Comment: Your question is quite long, so hard to digest, at least for me. Is there anything in it that could be shortened/removed/simplified?

Comment: Also, I see several bad ideas in the code: the map for which value and key are the same seeds odd to me, and a waste of memory, plus the class is mutable so it makes it a dangerous key type for a hash map, then I don't see why the nodes should record they have been visited although you can track that externally in a set.

Comment: @Dici If i thought i could omit anything, i would have done. IMHO, this is the shortest way *I* can explain my problem. Perhaps someone with better english and better Java could tell this more simple.

Comment: I finished reading the question and agree with @second. You shouldn't use a wildcard here, wildcards are just used to make some signatures more reusable since Java generics aren't covariant, which make generic signatures less reusable if they don't use any wildcard. It doesn't really break encapsulation in any way because just have a generic type doesn't give you any information about this type if it's not bounded (by super of extends), and will never give you access to private members of this class (which would definitely break encapsulation)

Comment: @Dici If you read some articles with the dijkstra flag, you will find that a Map with identical Key and Value is a standard. Btw: This is how a HashSet is implemented. I will think about the implementation of visited as a Set instead of a boolean field. In my solution, you have a read and a change of a boolean. In your solution, you have a remove from a set and an add/put to another set. Sounds as if your proposal *might* be a *bit* slower, but i dare to predict that the differences are not too big. If everything else is running, i will give it a try and look for the runtimes.

Comment: @second: Sry for readability. LSGraph consists of 3 paragraphs, fspHelper is a method of LSGraph<E>, whence the E comes. I cannot explain the wildcard capture, that is an idea i learned only today about.

Comment: Mmm ok, I never implemented it like that myself but perhaps it's a common thing to do. As for `HashSet`'s implementation, it is indeed backed by a map but the values aren't the keys themselves, it's a singleton object: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java#l219

Comment: Ok. I justed my sample code with that information. I still get an `The method executeMove(T) in the type LSElement<T> is not applicable for the arguments (M)` if I use the syntax from my first comment. So for that to work there must be a relation between `M` and `T`. But this is not defined. (so its basically the same issue just a bit more readable without the wildcards)

Comment: @Dici: Never looked up the sources of HashSet :-) Perhaps it’s an idea to extend HashSet and implement get(K) ...

Comment: @second: i also tried LSElement<T extends Object>. And surely M DOES extend Object. Did not help.

Comment: @ChristianH.Kuhn to be fair I was wrong when I said using values as keys is a waste of memory, it doesn't cost any additional memory because the values are just nodes that store a reference to the already existing key, so it only has the cost of a reference. Anyhow! Could you share the whole code in a gist or something? I feel it would make it easier for me to grasp what you're trying to do and attempt fixing it

Comment: @Dici: I can, but not the next hours. Monday, perhaps Tuesday.

Comment: Mmm alright. For your comment about `get`, which is a bit off-topic but interests me, I still don't get why you need this. If you do `set.contains(t)` and it returns `true`, you already have `t` since you passed it as an argument, why would you need to get it returned to you? This would only make sense if you are mutating the values and not the keys, and that your hash function is not defined over all the attributes of the class. Is this what you're doing? In that case I can understand, although I find it quite confusing and a bit unsafe.

Comment: After a few changes to classes and interfaces I got some version of `fspHelper` that compiles. But its probably not what you are looking for? Should I post it anyway, maybe its helpfull as reference?

Comment: @second I think you should post it, it would help us discuss about some concrete code and figure out what the exact requirements are

Answer (score 1):

Changing the graph class definition to `public static class LSGraph<MOVE, E extends LSElement<MOVE>> {`, I can get this snippet to compile just fine:

```
final List<MOVE> moves = actNode.getElement().findLegalMoves();
actNode.getElement().executeMove(moves.get(0));
```

Is it not the type of call you want to be able to make? Now if you're asking why you can't call the method the way you've done it, let's talk about wildcards. Note that what I'm about to explain is also available in [Oracle's Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

```
final List<?> moves = actNode.getElement().findLegalMoves();
fspHelper(moves, actNode);

private <M> void fspHelper(final List<M> moves, final LSNode<E> actNode) {
    for (final M move : moves) {
        final LSNode<E> newNode = new LSNode<>(actNode.getElement().executeMove(move));
    }
}
```

Since the compiler doesn't know anything about the elements inside of `moves`, `M` is not going to be any better than `?` (which basically means the type is unknown), and you can never pass an argument of "type ?" to a method since the compiler would be unable to verify the call is valid and will not result in inconsistencies. The only thing you can do with a wildcard is *reading* values. For example, if you have the following function:

```
public void doStuff(List<? extends Move> moves) {
    Move move = moves.get(0);
}
```

As you can see, I am allowed to read from the list and declare the first element as a specific type `Move` thanks to the type bound in the declaration. But now if I try to add this value back to the list with `moves.add(move)`, it won't work because the type of the list is `?`, so the `add` method requires me to pass a parameter of this type, which is forbidden. That's for a good reason: all values from `moves` are subclasses of `Move`, but since we don't know anything about the most specific common supertype of all elements in the list, we have no idea whether a new instance with supertype `Move` is suitable to be to be added to this list or not. It is impossible to know if `moves.add(move)` is legal or not no matter the type of `move`, so it is forbidden.

To be clear, here's the sole reason wildcard exists and what it should be used for:

```
List<Animal> singleCow = Arrays.asList(new Cow());
List<Animal> cowAndPig = Arrays.asList(new Cow(), new Pig());
List<Rabbit> rabbits = Arrays.asList(new Rabbit(), new Rabbit());
List<Mammal> mammals = Arrays.asList(new Rabbit(), new Rat());

doStuff(singleCow); // valid because exactly matches the signature
doStuff(cowAndPig); // valid because exactly matches the signature

doStuff(rabbits); // you'd think it works because Rabbit is a subtype of Animal, but it doesn't compile because Java generics are invariant
doStuffWithWildcard(rabbits); // this one compiles because it allows having a list of something else than exactly the type Animal as long as it's a subtype of it

doStuff(mammals); // doesn't compile for the same reason as above
doStuffWithWildcard(mammals); // compiles for the same reason as above

public void doStuff(List<Animal> animals) { }
public void doStuffWithWildcard(List<? extends Animal> animals) { }
```

As you can see, the wildcard is a way to cope with Java's fairly weak type system and make some of your signatures more reusable. What I advise you in your code is **to not use any wildcard** and possibly even remove `E extends LSElement...`. I don't see what it brings you, you can implement what you want with only a `MOVE` generic type that you carry in all your classes, as this is the only thing that is generic in your Dijkstra.

Comment: So your deduction is that `M` and `T` are the same?

Comment: Mmm well not exactly but I think I know what you mean by this. Basically I'm saying your helper doesn't really help the compiler figure out anything interesting about the type that is stored in the list, so it still cannot ensure that it is safe to pass a given instance from the list as a parameter of any generic method, so it will simply forbid you to do so to prevent you from introducing type inconsistencies leading to runtime bugs.

Comment: Bring on the code to make this clearer. To me this helper makes no sense, what this code needs is to not use the wilcard in the graph class declaration in the first place. I'll be happy to look at your code and make up my mind about it but I don't think any hacky helper is going to look neater than simply not using a wildcard!

Comment: I added it. And yes I didn't really look at the problem itself, instead I focused on the compiler issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use the following definition (as suggested by Dici answer):

```
public class LSGraph<MoveType, E extends LSElement<MoveType>> {
  ...
}

public final class LSNode<MoveType, E extends LSElement<MoveType>> {
  ...
}
```

This make your definition harder to read and enforce `LSGraph` to know the type of move (although it is only to resolve a compilation issue).

If that is not acceptable, then you can also try raw types:

```
LSElement element = actNode.getElement();
final List moves = element.findLegalMoves();
for (Object move : moves) {
  LSElement newElement = element.executeMove(move);
}
```

Note that there some (hopefully rare) case where you are simply forced to do that: this is probably fine in your case, because `findLegalMoves` would never send an `Object` not being acceptable by `executedMove`.

For example, if T is `CardMove` then the `findLegalMoves` would return `List<CardMove>` and `executeMove` would only accept `CardMove`; an error would occur if `findLegalMoves` were returning a list containing something else than a `CardMove`:

- There would be a compilation error in `findLegalMoves` unless something ugly is done too (eg: raw type, cast)
- And for other case, there would be `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Uh, would definitely not advise using raw types! Dijsktra isn't so complicated that it's impossible to model it using Java generics. I think the best is in fact not to have `E` at all, it's not really needed from what U can see and adds a layer of abstraction. My answer is focused on wildcard usage though, because I thought this was the most interesting part about the question. Btw I don't really see what's the big deal with a generic class "knowing" about a generic type. Is it a problem that `List<T>` knows about `T`? It in fact doesn't know anything about it, since it's generic.

Comment: End of the comment since it was too long: arguably, why wouldn't a graph know something about the transitions (here, the `Move` generic type) that are allowed in this graph? Seems pretty ok to me.

Comment: @Dici: and that's why I said "I would personally use [...]". This is, however, an alternative.

Comment: Mmm yeah ok. I would have emphasized more loudly that I strongly advise against raw types though, but it depends how strongly you personally feel about it.

Answer (score 0):

Having not thought about this problem for two months, i have come to the conclusion that the interface `LSElement` is badly designed. It should be sufficient to know about elements; that there are moves (or edges) is an intern information that should not be public. So i think

```
public interface LSElement extends Comparable<LSElement> {
    List<LSElement> findAllNeighbours();
    void goToNeighbour(LSElement neighbour);
}
```

might be more appropriate.

Comment: And even that is not what i want. If i know the neighbours, i can go to a neighbour by simple putting it in a variable. No need for goToNeighbour().